# How do I select the pandas rows with certain conditions?

Tags: pandas, select, conditional-statements

I have a pandas frame called df, I wish to select only the rows which have some conditions.

I have one column called 'Country' and one called 'Type'.

I want to select all the rows in which the 'Country' says "South Korea" and the 'Type' is not empty.

I tried the following code `df = df[df['Country'] == 'South Korea' & ~df['Type'].empty()]`

But I get the following error, `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`. How do I select the rows with the conditions I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: i checked out this post, i keep getting errors as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using paranthesis and `notna`:

```
df = df.loc[(df['Country'] == 'South Korea') & (df['Type'].notna())]
```

Comment: now it says TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [bool] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Comment: That is a strange error.  What does type(df) return?

Comment: when i separate the commands, it works, but when I try to combine them it doesnt, ive never had this happen before

Comment: Are you using the word "and' Or the "&" ampersand symbol?  And the paranthesis are necessary.

Comment: im using & if I use 'and' i get this error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: if i add .loc i get TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [bool] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Comment: This error is happening on a different line of code.

Comment: You have to have df.loc[(Condition1) & (condition2)]... You must use paranthesis and the & symbol.

Comment: haha that solved it, i was missing the parenthesis on the first condition, thanks!, I totally didnt notice it.